# How to secure a single url in a weblogic application?

Tags: security, weblogic, web.xml

**UPDATE 2:** 
What seems to be the root of the problem is that I can only succesfully secure the root of the application (e.g. the "/"). When I try to secure any other url, it gives me a 403. Unsecured urls work without problem.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**
I made this basic application where I want to be able have one secured page and one unsecured page. I currently get a 403 whenever I try to access my secured page (after giving the correct login data). Below I've posted my web.xml I have been trying to work with. I can access the unsecured page with no problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_10" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
  <display-name>Login test</display-name>

<!-- Servlet config -->   
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>AfterLoginServlet</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>test.AfterLoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AfterLoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/secured</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UnsecuredServlet</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>test.UnsecuredServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UnsecuredServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/unsecured</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

<!-- Login and security config -->  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.Login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <security-role>
    <role-name>demorole</role-name>
  </security-role>

  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>secured pages</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/secured</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>demorole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>MyRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/error</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>

  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
  </session-config>

</web-app>
```

I've tried a few other options to make sure my application was working.

1. Turned security off completely: this worked without a hitch.
2. Set security to everything: I adapted the `security-constraint` to have the `url-pattern` be `/*`. This made me able to access only `/` (if I changed my servlet mapping).

So I succeed at securing either all pages or none of my pages, but I don't manage to secure only a portion of them. I don't really know what I could be doing wrong (though I'm sure it's something stupid).

**UPDATE 1:**
I have 2 working options now (for my simple test case):
    
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
      Login test

```
<!-- Servlet config -->   
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>AfterLoginServlet</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>test.AfterLoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AfterLoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UnsecuredServlet</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>test.UnsecuredServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UnsecuredServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/unsecured</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

<!-- Login and security config -->  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.Login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <security-role>
    <role-name>demorole</role-name>
  </security-role>

  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>unsecured</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/unsecured</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
  </security-constraint>

  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>secured pages</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>demorole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>MyRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/error</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>

  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
  </session-config>

</web-app>
```

I can also change the servlet mapping for AfterLoginServlet to /*. This still works on the / url, but not anything else...

**UPDATE 3: Roles**

So I actually have several applications that all suffer that same problem with security having to be /*.
I've used to possible configurations for roles that work:

1. The one you see here with demorole (defined role in web.xml and defined security-role assigment in weblogic.xml)
   For this one, when I look in Security Realms -> [realm name] -> Roles and Policies -> Realm Roles, I see for every application that uses that role `URL Pattern:/ Role:demorole` in  -> Web module -> Url Patterns and Role
2. One where I do not define a role and I just use `All` in the security constraint (no extra definitions in web.xml or weblogic.xml):

.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>all</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>All</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the weblogic.xml file:

```
<security-role-assignment>
        <role-name>demorole</role-name>
        <externally-defined/>
</security-role-assignment>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I tried this, but I still get the 403. Do you have any other suggestions? Could I supply you with more information that would help you pinpoint the problem?

Comment: What repository are you authenticating against? Where do you have demorole defined?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have demorole defined in the web.xml. 
I also have security-role assignment with a principal-name for demorole defined in the weblogic.xml.
There are number of authentication providers defined for my domain that are supplied by my company (so non-standard ones).
Now, I managed to find a working configuration (see my answer below), but I don't really know why it works. So while this has solved my immediate problem, I'm still wondering what was wrong with my previous approach.

Comment: With some more testing, I think I've pinpointed the problem a bit more. I updated my question with my findings and with the configuration that does work.

Comment: Where do you define what users are in the demorole? Is that in your LDAP repository or do you have WebLogic roles (Security Realms -> [realm name] -> Roles and Policies -> Realm Roles?

Comment: I've updated my question based with extra information on roles and with the info on them I could find in the weblogic console.